# DynamoDB Scan Lambda function returns HTTP request or something that I do not understand, but not list of items

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, api-gateway

I've deployed a Lambda function, which should get list of items with a `scan(params, cb)` function. In console, I see something different, not the returned list, but something that lookgs like http request body or response?

Can you please explain how to get the list correctly and what do I get?

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('function started')
    let params = {
        TableName: "documents"
    }

    console.log('params get')
    let respond = await db.scan(params, (err, data) => {
        console.log('scan started')
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else {
            console.log('else started')

           return data
        }
    })
    console.log('Respons IS: ')
    console.log(respond)
};
```

The response is a huge huge huge list of something:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) ES6 feature.

I advise you to only use the latter in this case.

Here is what it would look like :

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const db = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('function started');
    const params = {
        TableName: "documents"
    };

    console.log('params get');
    const respond = await db.scan(params).promise();
    console.log('Respons IS: ');
    console.log(respond);

    return ...
};
```

Comment: thank you very much!:) I understand why you use promise (but it should work with callbacks also, am I wrong?), but can you explain what is DynamoDB.DocumentClient() and why I can't find it on official documentation of aws-sdk? 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Comment: You are welcome.
To answer your question : yes you can totally use callbacks.
Here is the `DocumentClient` documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html